# What's up with my calculator?

Tags: lateral-thinking, number-sequence

As I am wont to do, I got a new calculator the other day. Obviously it needed a few test calculations:

```
5 + 6 = 11  
22 - 17 = 5
10 + 3 = 13
4 * 6 = 24
```

OK, so far so good. But there were also a bunch of weird results that I don't understand:

```
2 * 1 = 10  
9 + 7 = 9
3 - 1 = 3
34 - 8 = 2
```

What's going on?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Your calculator seems to be

> replacing the numbers with how many segments they have lit up on a standard 7-segment display, and doing the calculations with those. (For example, "22" has 10 segments and "17" has 5 segments, so "22 - 17" turns into 10 - 5, which is 5.)

Comment: He's good! You can't fool Deus!

Comment: Exactly right, well done!